# Make a graphviz branch, branch out to two or more branches

Tags: graphviz

I have the following code which produces the tree as shown.

```
digraph branch {
    graph [rankdir="LR", splines=ortho];
    node [shape=record];

    l1 [label="A\l|B\l"];
    l2 [label="C\l|D\l"];
    l3 [label="E\l|F\l"];

    l1 -> l2 [sametail=1];
    l1 -> l3 [sametail=1];
}
```

However, I want the left to right arrow branch as shown by red lines.

[image]

How do I do this?

Using `sametail` did not work, as you can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, it can only be done by creating invisible nodes for the joints:

```
digraph branch {
    graph [rankdir="LR", splines=ortho];
    node [shape=record];

    l1 [label="A\l|B\l"];
    l2 [label="C\l|D\l"];
    l3 [label="E\l|F\l"];
    joint [shape="none", label="", width=0, height=0]

    l1 -> joint [arrowhead="none"];
    joint -> l2; 
    joint -> l3; 
}
```

Output will look like this:

[image: Output]